# Am I wrongly converting VGG19 based Style Transfer pytorch model to ONNX?

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, onnx

https://github.com/safwankdb/Neural-Style-Transfer
I created a model file by running the code in the link above. I then converted it to ONNX to run with C++ and OpenCV.
But while Input (1,3,512,512) in the ONNX file I exported, it is in the form (1,512,28,28) in Output. My export code:

```
VGG.eval()
torch.save(VGG, 'torchmodel.pth')
dummy_input = Variable(torch.randn(1, 3, 512, 512, device='cuda:1'))
input_names = ['input']
output_names = ['output']
onnxfile='style.onnx'
torch.onnx.export(VGG,dummy_input,onnxfile,verbose=False,input_names=input_names,opset_version=11, output_names=output_names)
```

I tried export parameters from some sites but it didn't work.

Does anyone have an opinion on this matter?

Original code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""StyleTransfer.ipynb

Automatically generated by Colaboratory.

Original file is located at
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15JKaqmpVNr8NhURJWgbkvIl1sd0aKS3o
"""

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision as tv
from PIL import Image
import imageio
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

to_tensor = tv.transforms.Compose([
            tv.transforms.Resize((512,512)),
            tv.transforms.ToTensor(),
            tv.transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                std=[1, 1, 1]),
        ])

unload = tv.transforms.Compose([
            tv.transforms.Normalize(mean=[-0.485,-0.456,-0.406],
                                std=[1,1,1]),                
            tv.transforms.Lambda(lambda x: x.clamp(0,1))
        ])
to_image = tv.transforms.ToPILImage()

style_img = 'udnie.jpg'
input_img = 'chicago.jpg'

style_img = Image.open(style_img)
input_img = Image.open(input_img)

style_img = to_tensor(style_img).cuda()
input_img = to_tensor(input_img).cuda()

def get_features(module, x, y):
#     print('here')
features.append(y)

def gram_matrix(x):

b, c, h, w = x.size()
F = x.view(b,c,h*w)
G = torch.bmm(F, F.transpose(1,2))/(h*w)
return G

VGG = tv.models.vgg19(pretrained=True).features
VGG.cuda()

for i, layer in enumerate(VGG):

if i in [0,5,10,19,21,28]:
    VGG[i].register_forward_hook(get_features)

elif isinstance(layer, nn.MaxPool2d):
    VGG[i] = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2)

VGG.eval()

for p in VGG.parameters():
    p.requires_grad = False

features = []
VGG(input_img.unsqueeze(0))
c_target = features[4].detach()

features = []
VGG(style_img.unsqueeze(0))
f_targets = features[:4]+features[5:]
gram_targets = [gram_matrix(i).detach() for i in f_targets]

alpha = 1
beta = 1e3
iterations = 200
image = input_img.clone().unsqueeze(0)
# image = torch.randn(1,3,512,512).cuda()
images = []
optimizer = optim.LBFGS([
image.requires_grad_()], lr=1)    
mse_loss = nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')
l_c = []
l_s = []
counter = 0

for itr in range(iterations):

    features = []
    def closure():
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        VGG(image)
        t_features = features[-6:]
        content = t_features[4]
        style_features = t_features[:4]+t_features[5:]
        t_features = []
        gram_styles = [gram_matrix(i) for i in style_features]
        c_loss = alpha * mse_loss(content, c_target)
        s_loss = 0

    for i in range(5):
        n_c = gram_styles[i].shape[0]
        s_loss += beta * mse_loss(gram_styles[i],gram_targets[i])/(n_c**2)

    total_loss = c_loss+s_loss

    l_c.append(c_loss)
    l_s.append(s_loss)
    
    total_loss.backward()
    return total_loss

optimizer.step(closure)

print('Step {}: S_loss: {:.8f} C_loss: {:.8f}'.format(itr, l_s[-1], l_c[-1]))


if itr%1 == 0:
    temp = unload(image[0].cpu().detach())
    temp = to_image(temp)
    temp = np.array(temp)
    images.append(temp)
    imageio.mimsave('progress.gif', images)
    

plt.clf()
plt.plot(l_c, label='Content Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('loss1.png')

plt.clf()
plt.plot(l_s, label='Style Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('loss2.png')

plt.imsave('last.jpg',images[-1])
```

Comment: Have you tried running the model with the same input dimensions using PyTorch?

Comment: I haven't tried anywhere else, but I can get an image in the original code.

Comment: You haven't tried but you did get an image as output?? Anyway, your code here outputs feature maps, not images.

Comment: I mean, I haven't tried it in any other code, but it shows a result with the above codes.
By the way, I think I understand what you're saying. This model gives feature maps instead of an image output directly. So I guess I should write a code to take and process this feature maps in C++. So where do you think I should start about this? There are 512 channels of tensors and the others are vectors of them?